# Parsing a String to add to an Array

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Let’s say I have a long string on a cell

A: 1/2/15 School Dog 9/20/19

B:(3 spaces)1/8/16 School Cat 10/10/10

I want to capture 1/2/15 and 1/8/16

Problem is 
first string is separated by 1 space 
second string is separated by 3 spaces

So for me

```
myStringArr = Split(myString,” “) 
MsgBox myStringArr(1)

myStringArr(1) = 1/2/15
```

Only works for the first string not the second string

What could I use instead of “single space” condition to parse the string and capture the 1st date everytime

Comment: Assuming you have strings starting with Dates data, you can use Trim VBA function to remove leading spaces from the strings and then follow your approach.

Comment: You cam also use regular expressions for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dairly simple, only if the structure of the string is like that.

```
dim tmp() as Variant
dim left_date, right_date as string
for each DatesinString in StringArray
    tmp = split(LTrim(DatesinString), " ")
    left_date = tmp(0)
    right_date = tmp(Ubound(tmp))

next DatesinString
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution using Regex. The user defined function takes two parameters: cell reference and the match number. The regex Execute method returns all matching patterns, and the function returns the appropriate match as requested (in case you want to return the second date in the input string). The matching date is returned as a date value, but this could be modified to return as a string by removing the CDate() function.

```
Function ExtractDate(rng As Range, matchNum As Integer) As Variant
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim target As Variant
    Dim regex As Object

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Pattern = "(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/[0-9]{2}"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = regex.Execute(rng.Value)

    If matchNum > 0 And matchNum <= matches.Count Then
        target = CDate(matches.Item(matchNum - 1).Value)
    Else
        target = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If

    ExtractDate = target
End Function
```

Example usage: `=ExtractDate(A1,2)`

This will return the second date found in the string in cell A1